# Create graph with curved and labelled edges in Networkx

Tags: python, matplotlib, networkx

I'm currently displaying directed graphs with few nodes and edges connecting them, with `nx.draw`.
The edges are labelled via `nx.draw_networkx_edge_labels`.

Now I wanted to "lighten" the "rigidity" aspect of the graph by setting the `connectionstyle`, which works fine with non-labelled edges.

Problem is that if I display labels, they are drawn as if the edge was not curved, which ends up creating a huge offset between the edge and the label.

Is there any way to work around this limitation? I could not find an "offset" option to `nx.draw_networkx_edge_labels` to address this issue.

**EDIT:**

Above is a quick example of the issue:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import networkx as nx

tab = ("r", ["s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"])

producer = tab[0]
consumers = tab[1]

color_map = []
DG = nx.DiGraph()
for i, cons in enumerate(consumers):
    DG.add_edge(producer, cons, label=f"edge-{i}")

for i in range(len(DG.nodes())):
    if i < 1 + len(consumers):
        color_map.append("#DCE46F")
    else:
        color_map.append("#6FA2E4")
pos = nx.shell_layout(DG)
labels = nx.get_edge_attributes(DG, 'label')
nx.draw(DG, pos, node_color=color_map, connectionstyle="arc3, rad=0.2", with_labels=True, font_size=8, node_size=1000, node_shape='o')
nx.draw_networkx_edge_labels(DG, pos, edge_labels=labels)

plt.show()
```

current output:

[image]

Comment: Can you please provide a minimal reproducible example?

Comment: Ok I'm gonna do that, I did not in a first time because I was limited in time. I'll do it ASAP.

Comment: I've edited the post with a reproducible example.

Comment: thanks for updating, the question is clear now!

Comment: You're welcome. Tbh, I don't think there is a clear solution to my problem. I plan on adding a color to edges and then using a legend to my graphs, even though I'd rather have labelled edges.

Comment: I haven't had a chance to look yet, but I'm hopeful (and if no solution is found, that might be the opportunity to request the function to the networkx dev)

Comment: @mozway This has been discussed [for several years now](https://github.com/networkx/networkx/issues/3813) but drawing simply is not a priority for networkx. It might still be some time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are open to using other libraries for the visualization, I wrote (and maintain) [`netgraph`](https://github.com/paulbrodersen/netgraph). In `netgraph`, edge labels track edges even if they are curved.

[image]

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import networkx as nx

from netgraph import Graph # pip install netgraph

tab = ("r", ["s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"])

producer = tab[0]
consumers = tab[1]

DG = nx.DiGraph()
for i, cons in enumerate(consumers):
    DG.add_edge(producer, cons, label=f"edge-{i}")

node_color = dict()
for node in DG:
    if node in producer:
        node_color[node] = "#DCE46F"
    else:
        node_color[node] = "#6FA2E4"

pos = nx.shell_layout(DG)
pos[producer] = pos[producer] + np.array([0.2, 0])
edge_labels = nx.get_edge_attributes(DG, 'label')

Graph(DG, node_layout=pos, edge_layout='curved', origin=(-1, -1), scale=(2, 2),
      node_color=node_color, node_size=8.,
      node_labels=True, node_label_fontdict=dict(size=10),
      edge_labels=edge_labels, edge_label_fontdict=dict(size=10),
)
plt.show()
```

Comment: I might give it a try, I just have to see if I can insert it in my PyQt app. The sample I provided you is normally integrated within matplotlib FigureCanvas with additional "ax" parameter, so I can try it. 
I also have to consider the problematic of maintainability in the long term.

Comment: additional question : it seems that the graph is not "directed" (arrow edge) in your example, is there a way to do it? It's way more important than labels in my case.

Comment: You can pass in an axis explicitly using the `ax` keyword argument. Arrows are plotted with `arrows=True`. For a full list of available arguments: [ReadTheDocs](https://netgraph.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). I know that others have made PyQt applications with it, so that should work fine.

Comment: W.r.t. maintainability: open source is exactly as well maintained as you want it to be. That being said, I have been working on netgraph for 8, maybe 9 years (oldest commit is from 6 years due to a rewrite), and as I still enjoy working on it, I don't think you have fear a complete abandonment any time soon.

Comment: Ty for your comment, I'll definitely give it a try soon (maybe after work ;) )

Comment: OK, I tested it and I liked it a lot. It also "sharpens" (sry for my mediocre english) the graph which makes it a bit fancier. 

I just had a RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in double_scalars
  rescale_factor = min(rescale_factor, diameter/np.sqrt(width**2 + height**2)), I'll have to monitor that but it's not worrying.

Comment: May I add another question? I'm discovering your python library, especially the InteractiveGraph which I'm really interested in.
However, I can't manage to make it work in my app. Would you mind to give me a tip on what I might be doing wrong? I did instantiate the InteractiveGraph class but still, I can't click the nodes. I can provide a code snippet.

Comment: To enable to interactive matplotlib events in PyQt, you need to set the focus in a particular way. See https://github.com/paulbrodersen/netgraph/issues/34 and the matplotlib issue linked in that thread. If it is not that, I would suggest to ask another question here on SO and tag it with PyQT, matplotlib and netgraph.

Comment: Or open an issue on my github. But you will get more eyes here.

Comment: Ok, I opened [a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72197530/clickable-netgraph-in-pyqt-application-with-tabs) on this topic. I tried the several suggestion made on your github repo or SO, but with no success.